# "Thanks for your edit!" message is showing up twice

Tags: bug, tags, edits, suggested-edits

This happend to me when I updated a tag. I think it happend because I edited both excerpt **and** description. IMHO the message should only appear once.

[image: screenshot showing "Thanks for your edit" twice]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design; have you noticed the two [peer reviewed] links? They point to [two](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13586663) [different](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13586664) reviews. Because they are two different edits (which would have resulted in +4 reputation, had they both been accepted), two messages are needed.